# Chart js - Line chart - How to hide the data label on the line?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm not talking about the y-axis nor the x-axis but the the label on the line.
I've searched the documentation and stack overflow but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Can you share some of your code please?

Comment: Please share the code to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking something like this.

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        display: false,
    },
}
```